# Can't access properties polymer in function

Tags: methods, properties, arguments, polymer

When I'm in a method of the object Polymer, I can't modify my properties. I don't know which argument to pass to the function.

```
<google-map-marker id="userMarker" latitude="{{locOrigin.lat}}" longitude="{{locOrigin.lng}}"></google-map-marker>

properties: {
        locOrigin: {
            type: Object,
            value: {}
        }
    },

ready: function(e) {
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.maPosition(), this.erreurPosition);               
        } else {
            alert("Ce navigateur ne supporte pas la géolocalisation");
        }
    },

maPosition: function (position, locOrigin) {
        locOrigin.lat  = position.coords.latitude;//locOrigin undifined
    },
```

Comment: From API google: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) BUT when I pass position here this.maPosition(position) I have a "position is not defined"

Comment: Is someone know how to access property inside a method to modify them?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to modify your object properly use the `set` method like this:

```
maPosition: function (position) {
  this.set('locOrigin.lat', position.coords.latitude);
}
```

BTW, in which context are you calling `maPosition`? (no need for the `locOrigin` parameter)

Comment: maPosition get the user postion. So I want to add this position in the property locOrigin to be able to get it outside of the element.

Comment: It's working also with notifyPath('locOrigin.lat', latUser); But I thought notifyPath fire an event or call observer. But nothing append...

Comment: I still have this.set is not a function. It's working when I call document.querySelector('carte-lieux').notifyPath/set